# How can CallKit be used to make a non-voip call?

Tags: ios, callkit

I would like to make a call from app using the new iOS 10 CallKit but using the default carrier.  Is it possible?  If so, how?

Currently using:

```
public void dial(String number) {
  NSURL url = new NSURL("tel://" + number);
  UIApplication.getSharedApplication().openURL(url);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to make a standard telephone call using the device's carrier and not via your own app (i.e. not as a "VoIP" call in your own app) then launching a `tel:` URL is still the way to do this. CallKit is only involved if your own app will be backing the call, but that is not the case if you are making a carrier-backed telephone call.

Comment: so that means it's still not possible to hand over the name of the callee to iOS in order to display this name on the call screen and also in the list of the recent calls (phone app) - when making an ordinary call via `tel:` scheme?

Comment: For that, you might check out the new Call Blocking & Identification extensions feature in iOS 10. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit/cxcalldirectorymanager and the 'Call Directory Extension' target template in Xcode 8 and the iOS 10 SDK.

Comment: Disappointing that they didn't support standard carrier as well as voip in CallKit.